# Exception Handling: "undefined method `____' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

One of the most common reasons my web application fails is because a user sometimes lacks a certain attribute that a view expects it to have. For instance, most users in my application have an education (school, degree, etc.) entry in our system, but some users do not. Assuming my view looks something like this:

```
<% @educations.each do |education| %>
  <%= education.school %>
  <%= education.degree %>
<% end %>
```

I want to avoid "Pokemon" exception handling and feel that there has to be a better way around dealing with a "undefined method `degree' for nil:NilClass" error in the case that a user does not have an education entry in our database. This just seems like an ugly/tedious fix:

```
<% @educations.each do |education| %>
  <% if education.school %>
    <%= education.school %>
  <% end %>
  <% if education.degree %>
   <%= education.degree %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any input is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like the problem you're running into is not that `degree` is nil, it's that one of your instances of `education` is nil (`undefined method 'degree' for nil:NilClass`). Where does `@educations` come from?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the first object you're working on won't be nil, the easiest way is to just do this:

```
- @educations.each do |education|
  = education.try :school
  = education.try :degree
```

The [#try](http://everydayrails.com/2011/04/28/rails-try-method.html) method is pretty handy. You can also call `.to_s` on anything you think might be nil, Ie:

```
- @educations.each do |education|
  = education.school.to_s
  = education.degree.to_s
```

This will convert nils to an empty string. This isn't as useful in the view IMO, but comes in handy a lot of times if you have input that is expecting to be a string and might be empty. Ie a method like:

```
def put_in_parenthesis(string)
  "(" + string.to_s + ")"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here.

The easiest to implement is the [try method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try). It is used like so:

```
<%= education.try( :degree ) %>
```

The problem is that `try()` is viewed as [a bit of an anti-pattern](https://gist.github.com/1602530). As the reference indicates, you can achieve similar functionality with something like:

```
<%= education && education.degree %>
```

This isn't really a lot different, intellectually, in my opinion. A popular way of handling this a little more cleanly is the [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), which is basically an object with defined neutral ("null") behavior.

Comment: FWIW he's not asking `if education` in the above example, and even if he did `if education && education.degree; education.degree; end` that would still be the very thing he's asking not to have to do. I think for really simple applications, like views, `#try` is totally appropriate.

Comment: He wouldn't have to wrap it in an if, it returns the last result that it evaluates. Fire up irb and try `'spice' && 'nice' && true && 'rice' && nil` and `'spice' && 'nice' && true && 'rice'`, for example. You can chain it as long as you want to, so it would handle stuff like `<%= education && education.degree && education.degree.date %>`. (I know you can chain try, as well as send it arguments.) Personally, I think that this is best solved by using the null object pattern, except in trivial cases (which is why I included it). I think that most uses of try could be avoided by good architecture

Comment: My bad, I misread your answer. Thanks for elaborating in the comment.

Comment: No worries. Actually, I'm glad you were keeping me honest. Your question made me think about why you might actually want to prefer && to try, and I think it boils down to being (potentially/arguably) easier to test, and almost certainly nicer to read, especially when using arguments.